# Go web server : cannot find anything on http://localhost:8080/handler

Tags: webserver, go

I am trying to learn web programming with Go.
I stared out with a simple "hello world" web server:

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "net/http"

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprint(w, "Hello, world")
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

And when I go to

```
http://localhost:8080/handler
```

in the browser, the browser can´t seem to find anything and nothing happens. What could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mapped your handler to the root (`"/"`) of your server.

Call it like this in your browser

```
http://localhost:8080/
```

If you want to map a service to a specific name you can do this :

```
http.HandleFunc("/something", handler)
```

Then you would type this in your browser :

```
http://localhost:8080/something
```

Comment: Thanks for noticing and the quick answer. But I it´s still not working unfortunatly so it has to be some other reason in addition to the one you pointed out.

Comment: ListenAndServe may return an error, check it : `log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))`. The rest of the code seems correct but there may be another problem (not possible to take this port for example).

Comment: Kill the process using it and it should work. And... you should almost always check returned errors ;)

Comment: Yup, now it works perfectly. Thanks and I will from now on ;)